# Register a text document content provider for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible to create a custom text document content provider for a Visual Studio extension? 
I need to create a custom file scheme like `foo-bar://` instead of `file://` to handle certain read-only documents.

With Visual Studio code, this is done with [TextDocumentContentProvider / Virtual Documents](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/virtual-documents)

Is it possible to do something similar for a Visual Studio extension?

Comment: Please try to refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/language-service-and-editor-extension-points?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @Mrhello is there something in there specifically i should check out?

Comment: I am afraid that VS does not have such flexible function. I suggest you could check [Extending Editor Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/language-service-and-editor-extension-points?view=vs-2019#extending-editor-options).